# Using clone method for polymorph effects in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I wasn't clear at all in my last question which regarded another topic (making it kinda XY question) so i'm going to start with basics. 
I have a list in class called List

```
    class List {

    private:
        struct Elem {
            Notification* notif;
            Elem* next;
            Elem(const Notification& OB) : notif(OB.clone()), next(nullptr) {}
        };
    Elem* first; };
I have a class Notification 

    class Notification {
    public:
      virtual Notification* clone() const { return new Notification(*this); }
      virtual write(ostream& os)const { return os << "Some text from class Notif";}
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Notification& OB) {
        OB.write(os); return os; } };
```

I also have a class Error that is derived from notification and should have differently defined operator <<

```
    class Error: public Notification {
    private:
        string error_text;

    public:
        Error* clone() const { return new Error(*this); }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Error& OBJ) {
            OBJ.Notification::write(os); os << OBJ.error_text << endl;
            return os;
        }
    };
```

Now i want to go print the list to the output by overriding operator <<

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const List& list) {
        List::Elem* new = list.first;
        while (new) {
            os << *(new->notification);
            new = new->next;
        }
        return os;
    }
```

But when i do `cout << list`in main i only get notification messages. Is there any way to work around operator << being a global friend function? Is polymorphism not working because it is a global function or because i am de-referencing the pointer when printing? I am already kind of lost..

**EDIT** - Solved

I owe an apology to 1201ProgramAlarm.

I needed to override write() but the thing is write doesn't need to return os because os is passed by reference, write() should actually return void. Also there is no need to override operator<< again. I can just override the method write(). By overriding write() i change the method that is going to be called when i call os << *(new->notification); in List which is exactly what i want to do

Comment: You need to add `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const List& list);` to List class in order for it to access the private member `.first`.

The `operator<<` implementation for the `Error` class calls `Notification::write(os)` and thus the text "Some text from class Notif" will be printed for the `Error` class as well before the `error_text` is printed. In your minimum example there is no way to set `error_text` and it is initialized as an empty string. That is, maybe the correct version is actually being called and it just prints the same thing as the one in `Notification` class.

Comment: You don't have an override of `write` in `Error`.

Comment: @darcamo I didnt want to overdo the example, i have constructor for error_text and operator << is actually in class List. And i dont mind "Some text from notif class" being printed the problem is no text from error_text shows up.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I dont see the reason to override it as i dont mind using the old version but also i want to add error_text. I tried overloading it and it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I owe an apology to 1201ProgramAlarm.

I needed to override `write()` but the thing is write doesnt need to return `os` because `os` is passed by reference, `write()` should actually return void. Also there is no need to override `operator<<` again. I can just override the method `write()`. By overriding `write()` i change the method that is going to be called when i call `os << *(new->notification);` in List which is exactly what i want to do.